# Knockout.js: ko.toJSON does not convert viewmodel to JSON

Tags: jquery, json, iis, knockout.js

I am having very strange issue of my viewmodels not being converted to JSON on IIS. If i debug the same code on my system, it works fine and converts viewmodesl to JSON. Same code does not produce the same result on IIS.

This is how my viewmodels look like after calling ko.toJSON on them.

On IIS:

```
"{"__ko_mapping__":{"ignore":[],"include":["_destroy"],"copy":[],"mappedProperties": {"__type":true,"Prop1":true,"Prop2":true,"Prop3":true,"Prop4":true,"Prop5":true}}}"
```

On Local

```
{"__type":"DealerModel","Prop1":"","Prop2":"","Prop3":"","Prop4":"","Prop5":"Some Name  ltd"}}}"
```

This is how my DealerModel class looks like:

```
[Serializable]
Public class DealerModel
{
    public string Porp1 { get; set; }
    public string Porp2 { get; set; }
    public string Porp3 { get; set; }
    public string Porp4 { get; set; }
    public string Porp5 { get; set; }
}
```

I guess the problem is somehow DealerModel is not being passed as type to JSON or something.

Has anyone faced this issue? What could be the problem here?

This is how i convert my viewmodesl to JS. The method on the server side expects arraylist.

```
            var jsonViewModel = '';
            jsonViewModel = ko.toJSON(myNameSpace.ViewModel1);
            jsonViewModel = jsonViewModel.replace(/\/Date\((.*?)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)");
            saveArray[0] = jsonViewModel

            jsonViewModel = ko.toJSON(myNameSpace.ViewModel2);
            jsonViewModel = jsonViewModel.replace(/\/Date\((.*?)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)");
            saveArray[1] = jsonViewModel

$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Services/SomeService.asmx/SaveObjects",
                cache: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data:"{args:" + ko.toJSON(saveArray) + "}",
                dataType: "json"
            });
```

SaveObjects method expects arrayList.

Comment: Don't know much about IIS, but the only thing I can think of is the character encoding, did you check it to see that it's not CP1252 on the server and UTF-8 on the local machine or something ?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to create the json? Something else is going on here.

Comment: @JasonMore : Updatedt the question.

Comment: I posted an answer, but you might need to post your endpoint code as well.

Comment: For some reason it seems like the objects other properties are included in the .toJSON() call on IIS. Try looking at hasOwnProperties or something similar ??

Comment: Ah, if its a JS issue, can you put it into a JsFiddle so we can debug? Here is one you can fork: http://jsfiddle.net/JasonMore/p6Vcc/

Answer (score 3):

```
ko.toJSON(saveArray);
```

It does not create json object . It will produce json string.

**To create json object Use**

```
ko.toJS(saveArray);
```

Note: for this to work on older browsers that have no native JSON serializer (e.g., IE 7 or earlier), you must also reference the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) library.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't `__ko_mapping__` added by the [ko.mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)?  It looks like the object has no properties, as if on IIS you were using ko.mapping and trying to pass an empty mapping options object, but swapping the parameters:

```
var mappingOptions = { };
var data = { "FirstName": "Bruce". "LastName": "Banner" };
var vmBad = ko.mapping.fromJS(mappingOptions, data);
var vmGood = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions);
```

vmBad will actually be a view model with just the hidden **ko_mapping** property that the mapping plugin uses...  If you have that, you need to use ko.mapping to convert back to json to remove that property.  ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8GVLJ/))

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do this:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Services/SomeService.asmx/SaveObjects",
            data: { args: saveArray }
        });
```

If this doesn't work, can you post your endpoint code as well?

**UPDATE**
I removed stuff out of your ajax post I didn't think you needed since I didn't see any callbacks with data from the server.

Comment: the problem is before that. the JSON data that i have posted in the question is from jsonViewModel = ko.toJSON(myNameSpace.ViewModel1); line. At that line, it does not translate my viewmodels to JSON.

Comment: Like i said, the problem is not the save call. problem is the JSON convert.

Answer (score -1):

when you call `ko.toJSON(myNameSpace.ViewModel1)` it should be `ko.toJSON(myNameSpace.ViewModel1())`. The execution of your view model will probably show your properties correctly.

Comment: This doesn't work : "Property 'viewModel' of object [object Window] is not a function"